# How can I strip the whitespace from Pandas DataFrame headers?

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace

I am parsing data from an Excel file that has extra white space in some of the column headings.

When I check the columns of the resulting dataframe, with `df.columns`, I see:

```
Index(['Year', 'Month ', 'Value'])
                     ^
#                    Note the unwanted trailing space on 'Month '
```

Consequently, I can't do:

`df["Month"]`

Because it will tell me the column is not found, as I asked for "Month", not "Month ".

My question, then, is how can I strip out the unwanted white space from the column headings?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082588/7758804) should be accepted, not the current one.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can give functions to the `rename` method. The `str.strip()` method should do what you want:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   Year  Month   Value
0     1       2      3

[1 rows x 3 columns]

In [6]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
Out[6]: 
   Year  Month  Value
0     1      2      3

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Note**: that this returns a `DataFrame` object and it's shown as output on screen, but the changes are not actually set on your columns. To make the changes, either use this in a method chain or re-assign the `df` variabe:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```

Comment: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()m axis=1) is necessary here so that the lambda fxn iterate through headers rather than index

Answer (score 115):

Since [version 0.16.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.16.1.html#string-methods-enhancements) you can just call [`.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) on the columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Here is a small example:

```
In [5]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Month ', 'Value'])
print(df.columns.tolist())
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.columns.tolist()

['Year', 'Month ', 'Value']
Out[5]:
['Year', 'Month', 'Value']
```

**Timings**

```
In[26]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[' year', ' month ', ' day', ' asdas ', ' asdas', 'as ', '  sa', ' asdas '])
df
Out[26]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ year,  month ,  day,  asdas ,  asdas, as ,   sa,  asdas ]


%timeit df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
%timeit df.columns.str.strip()
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop
```

So `str.strip` is ~2X faster, I expect this to scale better for larger dfs

Answer (score 16):

If you use CSV format to export from Excel and read as Pandas DataFrame, you can specify:

```
skipinitialspace=True
```

when calling `pd.read_csv`.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> skipinitialspace : bool, default False
>
> ```
> Skip spaces after delimiter.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't skip trailing spaces per the OP's example.  There doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to do this, particularly for multi-row headers which create MultiIndexes.  It can be done, but it should be easier.

Comment: @TerryBrown: It doesn't help in the general case, that's true, and also why my answer begins with an "if". I've often seen whitespaces in Dataframes imported from CSV, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an unbreakable way to do it, I would suggest:

```py
data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Upvoted!

This is where my mind went since I like to strip whitespace earlier in my process flow and handle incoming data with variable headers (nans, ints, etc). 

Using the isinstance(var, type) check slows it down sure - but how many headers are we talking? Here I'd exchange the flexibility for computation since I don't forsee bringing in a header set of more than 25 columns...and definitely not more than 500...

Answer (score 4):

Actually can do that with

```
df.rename(str.strip, axis = 'columns')
```

Which is shown in Pandas documentation
[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).