# Pythonic/efficient way to strip whitespace from every Pandas Data frame cell that has a stringlike object in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a CSV file into a DataFrame.  I need to strip whitespace from all the stringlike cells, leaving the other cells unchanged in Python 2.7.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
def remove_whitespace( x ):
    if isinstance( x, basestring ):
        return x.strip()
    else:
        return x

my_data = my_data.applymap( remove_whitespace )
```

Is there a better or more idiomatic to Pandas way to do this?

Is there a more efficient way (perhaps by doing things column wise)?

I've tried searching for a definitive answer, but most questions on this topic seem to be how to strip whitespace from the column names themselves, or presume the cells are all strings.

Comment: What would happen if you were to do x.strip() on an element that is not an instance of a basestring? If there aren't any downsides maybe you could remove the check and replace it with a try and except block. That might speed things up.

Comment: Are you using `pandas.read_csv` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?  Have you tried `skipinitialspace=True`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I might have whitespace both before and after the data I care about in the cell, so I think skipinitialspace only fixes half the problem.

Comment: @JeffMandell - attempting to call .strip() on a non-stringlike object (or thing that doesn't have a strip method, such as a numeric data type) will raise an exception.  You're right that handling the exception could be faster than doing the check - depending on the data and frequency of exceptions.

Comment: @deadcode I was afraid that might be the case.

Comment: @deadcode The one concern with the solution that I offered is that an object other than a base string might have the strip() function. This could lead to a hard to notice bug.

Comment: This question looks very similar to, and was imho answered in a great way in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950310/strip-trim-all-values-of-a-dataframe

Comment: NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined. "The builtin basestring abstract type was removed [in python3]. Use str instead."

Answer (score 110):

Stumbled onto this question while looking for a quick and minimalistic snippet I could use. Had to assemble one myself from posts above. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
data_frame_trimmed = data_frame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

Comment: This did the job. In case even your headers have trailing spaces, add a `.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607530/4355695

Comment: This method failed for me if Pandas labeled a column as `object`. Pandas will label columns with mixed datatypes as `object` which doesn't necessarily mean that every element in that column is a `str`.

Comment: Michael, for truly mixed types, you can use OP method.

Comment: maybe isinstance(x, str) would be a better solution to check if it a string or not...

Comment: Another method is to use try except in a named function.
    def strip(x):
        result = x
        try:
            result = x.astype(unicode).str.strip()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return result
    
    data_frame_trimmed = data_frame.apply(strip)

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein In many cases, you can first convert all columns to numeric with the `errors='ignore'` argument (this ignores any column that has values that would cause an error when casting it to numeric): `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')`. Then you can more safely use this snippet to strip whitespace.

Answer (score 46):

You could use pandas' `Series.str.strip()` method to do this quickly for each string-like column:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['   ABC   ', '   DEF', '  GHI  ']})
>>> data
      values
0     ABC   
1        DEF
2      GHI  

>>> data['values'].str.strip()
0    ABC
1    DEF
2    GHI
Name: values, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 18):

We want to:

1. Apply our function to each element in our dataframe - use `applymap`.
2. Use `type(x)==str` (versus `x.dtype == 'object'`) because Pandas will label columns as `object` for columns of mixed datatypes (an `object` column may contain `int` and/or `str`).
3. Maintain the datatype of each element (we don't want to convert everything to a `str` and then strip whitespace).

Therefore, I've found the following to be the easiest:

`df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x)==str else x)`

Comment: An alternative syntax for checking datatypes: `isinstance(x, str)` instead of `type(x)==str`

Comment: This seems to provide adequate level of precision without being overly aggressive and potentially destructive.

Answer (score 14):

When you call `pandas.read_csv`, you can use a regular expression that matches zero or more spaces followed by a comma followed by zero or more spaces as the delimiter.

For example, here's `"data.csv"`:

```
In [19]: !cat data.csv
1.5, aaa,  bbb ,  ddd     , 10 ,  XXX   
2.5, eee, fff  ,       ggg, 20 ,     YYY
```

(The first line ends with three spaces after `XXX`, while the second line ends at the last `Y`.)

The following uses `pandas.read_csv()` to read the files, with the regular expression `' *, *'` as the delimiter.  (Using a regular expression as the delimiter is only available in the "python" engine of `read_csv()`.)

```
In [20]: import pandas as pd

In [21]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, delimiter=' *, *', engine='python')

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
     0    1    2    3   4    5
0  1.5  aaa  bbb  ddd  10  XXX
1  2.5  eee  fff  ggg  20  YYY
```

Comment: This is very close, but has a problem with quoted input values, such as this:
"a, b, c   ",d
It can't pull the spaces off the first field which I would want stored in the dataframe's cell as 'a, b, c'

Answer (score 4):

The "data['values'].str.strip()" answer above did not work for me, but I found a simple work around.  I am sure there is a better way to do this.  The str.strip() function works on Series.  Thus, I converted the dataframe column into a Series, stripped the whitespace, replaced the converted column back into the dataframe.  Below is the example code.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['   ABC   ', '   DEF', '  GHI  ']})
print ('-----')
print (data)

data['values'].str.strip()
print ('-----')
print (data)

new = pd.Series([])
new = data['values'].str.strip()
data['values'] = new
print ('-----')
print (new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a column-wise solution with pandas apply:

```
import numpy as np

def strip_obj(col):
    if col.dtypes == object:
        return (col.astype(str)
                   .str.strip()
                   .replace({'nan': np.nan}))
    return col

df = df.apply(strip_obj, axis=0)
```

This will convert values in object type columns to string.  Should take caution with mixed-type columns.  For example if your column is zip codes with 20001 and ' 21110 '  you will end up with '20001' and '21110'.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - applies it to the whole dataframe:

```
def panda_strip(x):
    r =[]
    for y in x:
        if isinstance(y, str):
            y = y.strip()

        r.append(y)
    return pd.Series(r)

df = df.apply(lambda x: panda_strip(x))
```

Comment: `df.apply(panda_strip)` is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code useful and something that would likely help others. This snippet will allow you to delete spaces in a column as well as in the entire DataFrame, depending on your use case.

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_whitespace(x):
    try:
        # remove spaces inside and outside of string
        x = "".join(x.split())

    except:
        pass
    return x

# Apply remove_whitespace to column only
df.orderId = df.orderId.apply(remove_whitespace)
print(df)


# Apply to remove_whitespace to entire Dataframe
df = df.applymap(remove_whitespace)
print(df)
```