# Pandas: filtered dataframe does not return any rows, but unfiltered does

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a Pandas dataframe from CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'mike.csv'
main_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Output of `print(main_df.shape)` is `(280, 23)`, so there are 280 rows in this dataframe.

However, when I next try to filter this dataframe by column values:

```
filtered_df = main_df.query('Status == "Active"')
print(filtered_df.shape)
```

, the output od `print(filtered_df.shape)` is `(0,23)`, so I don't get any rows.

There is no mistake in column name or value name, as per below output of `print(main_df.loc[:5, "Status"])`:

```
0    Active   
1    Draft    
2    Draft    
3    Draft    
4    Active   
5    Active   
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Difficult to help as we don't know your data. Can you check `Status in main_df.columns` i.e. the output of `main_df['Status']` and whether `Active` really starts with a capital A?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question with example output from main dataframe, I guess it proves that there are no mistakes in column and value names.

Comment: Are you sure there's no unwanted whitespace in your series? For example, "Active " may not show up when you use `print`.

Comment: No trailing spaces in the `Status` column?

Comment: Indeed, could you try: `df['Status'] = df['Status'].str.strip()`?

Comment: @Cleb, this worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear! @jpp: Hope you don't mind that I turned your idea into an answer!?

Comment: @Cleb, No problem at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, a potential problem could be white spaces that are not visible when you print your data. You can remove them using [`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].str.strip()
```

Then

```
filtered_df = main_df.query('Status == "Active"')
```

should yield the desired output.

Comment: How would I convert this to a loop to strip whitespaces in all columns? I tried `for column in list(main_df): main_df[column].str.strip()`, but this gives me `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: If all your columns are of type string, you can use `apply`: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())`.

Comment: Hmm, they are not all strings, hence the error above.

Comment: Ok, then you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950485/1534017).