# Pandas python replace empty lines with string

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a csv which at some point becomes like this:

```
  57926,57927,"79961', 'dsfdfdf'",fdfdfdfd,0.40997048,5 x fdfdfdfd,
57927,57928,"fb0ec52878b165aa14ae302e6064aa636f9ca11aa11f5', 'fdfd'",fdfdfd,1.64948454,20 fdfdfdfd,"



                         US 



                "
57928,57929,"f55bf599dba600550de724a0bec11166b2c470f98aa06', 'fdfdf'",fdfdfd,0.81300813,10 fdfdfdfd,"



                         US 







                "
57929,57930,"82e6b', 'reetrtrt'",trtretrtr,0.79783365,fdfdfdf,"



                         NL
```

I want to get rid of this empty lines. So far I tried the following script :

```
df = pd.read_csv("scedon_etoimo.csv")

df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

and

```
df=df.replace(r'\r\r\r\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '',regex=True)
```

as this is the error I am getting. So far I haven't manage to clean my file and do the stuff I want to do. I am not sure if I am using the correct approach. I am using pandas to process my dataset. Any help?
                    "

Comment: the format looks invalid to me (different amount of cols perrow). is this the actual file?

Comment: @Gerasimos, you need to add an additional `"` to the end of your sample file. Right now the open quotes will break attempts to read your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I would first `open` and *preprocess* the file's data, and *just then* pass to pandas

```
lines = []
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): lines.append(line.strip())

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(lines)))
```

Comment: Another option is to read the file into a dataframe, and then post-process with the `str.strip` function using the dataframe `apply` or assignment as in the accepted answer for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950310/strip-trim-all-strings-of-a-dataframe

Comment: I also tried `df.replace('\s+', '',regex=True,inplace=True)` and worked. Anyway, thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the file snippet you provided, here is how you can replace those empty lines Pandas is storing as NaNs with a blank string.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("scedon_etoimo.csv")
df = df.replace(np.nan, "", regex=True)
```

This will allow you to do everything on the base Pandas DataFrame without reading through your file(s) more than once. That being said, I would also recommend preprocessing your data before loading it in as that is often times a much safer way to handle data in non-uniform layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.replace(to_replace=r'[\n\r\t]', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This instruction replaces each `\n`, `\r` and `Tab` with nothing.
Due to `inplace` argument, no need to substitute the result to `df` again.

Alternative: Use `to_replace=r'\s'` to eliminate also spaces,
maybe in selected columns only.