# remove row in pandas column based on "if string in cell" condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some columns, one of this is `Text` that contains some text (obv).

Several cells of this columns have "no text" in there, but I have noticed ( I don't know why) that there are some spaces: for example in some rows I have `"no text"` in others `" no text"` , `"  no text  "` and `"  no text  "` and so on.

I thought to use a condition like this to remove the rows whose column `Text` misses it:

```
data = data.drop(data['no text' in data['Text']].index)
```

but gives me some errors (`KeyError: '[False] not found in axis'`)
I know that for stuff like this, one have to pass a boolean condition, `df = df.drop(df[boolean_cond])`  so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can apply str.strip() to the column, as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950310/strip-trim-all-strings-of-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)**

If you want to remove rows which contain string as `no text` then you can do this:

```
data = data[~(data['Text'].str.contains("no text"))]
```