# AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values

Tags: python, pandas

This is not a dupe! I've been through all related questions and they don't answer my problem.

I'm using standard method for stripping spaces from pandas string columns as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950485/2119941):

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

But keep getting:

> c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py
> in _validate(data)    if inferred_dtype not in
> allowed_types: raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
> return inferred_dtype
>
> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

And when I run `print(df_obj .dtypes)` I get all columns listed as '`object`'.
So what's the problem?

Pandas version: '1.1.4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by converting columns to string by modifying 2. line:

```
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.astype('str').str.strip())
```

Never before have I had to use this on `object` column..I thought object columns where strings by default...