# python pandas merge dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to merge these 2 tables by origin, destination and carrier?

The first table has the column medium need and i need to add this filed into the 2 table, based on origin+destination+carrier values.
The response should be in a new column in the 2 table.

I tried to do `pandas.merge(1st table, 2 table)` but it didn't help.

Please help me with this question

1 table:

`{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19}, 'origin': {0: 'NEW YORK', 1: 'NEW YORK', 2: 'NEW YORK', 3: 'NEW YORK', 4: 'NEW YORK', 5: 'NEW YORK', 6: 'NEW YORK', 7: 'NEW YORK', 8: 'NEW YORK', 9: 'NEW YORK', 10: 'NEW YORK', 11: 'NEW YORK', 12: 'NEW YORK', 13: 'NEW YORK', 14: 'NEW YORK', 15: 'NEW YORK', 16: 'NEW YORK', 17: 'NEW YORK', 18: 'NEW YORK', 19: 'NEW YORK'}, 'destination': {0: 'Aqaba', 1: 'Aqaba', 2: 'Batumi', 3: 'Benghazi', 4: 'Benghazi', 5: 'Bremerhaven', 6: 'El Khoms', 7: 'El Khoms', 8: 'El Khoms', 9: 'Jebel Ali', 10: 'Jebel Ali', 11: 'Jebel Ali', 12: 'Klaipeda', 13: 'Klaipeda', 14: 'MISURATA', 15: 'MISURATA', 16: 'MISURATA', 17: 'Novorossiysk', 18: 'Odessa', 19: 'Odessa'}, 'carrier_name': {0: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 1: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 2: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 3: 'CGM', 4: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 5: 'CGM', 6: 'CGM', 7: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 8: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 9: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 10: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 11: 'ONE NETWORK EXPRESS', 12: 'CGM', 13: 'EVERGREEN INTERNATIONAL (U S A)', 14: 'CGM', 15: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 16: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 17: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 18: 'CGM', 19: 'Cosco Container Line'}, 'medium need': {0: 20.0, 1: 19.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 30.0, 4: 26.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 15.0, 7: 11.0, 8: 12.0, 9: 15.0, 10: 18.0, 11: 16.0, 12: 16.0, 13: 10.0, 14: 7.0, 15: 6.0, 16: 7.0, 17: 6.0, 18: 42.0, 19: 26.0}}`

2 table:

`{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19}, 'origin': {0: 'NEW YORK', 1: 'NEW YORK', 2: 'NEW YORK', 3: 'NEW YORK', 4: 'NEW YORK', 5: 'NEW YORK', 6: 'NEW YORK', 7: 'NEW YORK', 8: 'NEW YORK', 9: 'NEW YORK', 10: 'NEW YORK', 11: 'NEW YORK', 12: 'NEW YORK', 13: 'NEW YORK', 14: 'NEW YORK', 15: 'NEW YORK', 16: 'NEW YORK', 17: 'NEW YORK', 18: 'NEW YORK', 19: 'NEW YORK'}, 'destination': {0: 'Aqaba ', 1: 'Aqaba ', 2: 'Aqaba ', 3: 'Aqaba ', 4: 'Aqaba ', 5: 'Aqaba ', 6: 'Aqaba ', 7: 'Aqaba ', 8: 'Aqaba ', 9: 'Aqaba ', 10: 'Aqaba ', 11: 'Aqaba ', 12: 'Aqaba ', 13: 'Aqaba ', 14: 'Aqaba ', 15: 'Aqaba ', 16: 'Aqaba ', 17: 'Aqaba ', 18: 'Aqaba ', 19: 'Aqaba '}, 'from_': {0: '3/22/2021', 1: '3/29/2021', 2: '4/05/2021', 3: '3/29/2021', 4: '4/05/2021', 5: '4/12/2021', 6: '3/22/2021', 7: '3/29/2021', 8: '4/12/2021', 9: '4/05/2021', 10: '4/05/2021', 11: '4/12/2021', 12: '4/12/2021', 13: '4/12/2021', 14: '3/22/2021', 15: '3/22/2021', 16: '3/22/2021', 17: '3/22/2021', 18: '4/12/2021', 19: '3/29/2021'}, 'to_': {0: '3/29/2021', 1: '4/05/2021', 2: '4/12/2021', 3: '4/05/2021', 4: '4/12/2021', 5: '4/19/2021', 6: '3/29/2021', 7: '4/05/2021', 8: '4/19/2021', 9: '4/12/2021', 10: '4/12/2021', 11: '4/19/2021', 12: '4/19/2021', 13: '4/19/2021', 14: '3/29/2021', 15: '3/29/2021', 16: '3/29/2021', 17: '3/29/2021', 18: '4/19/2021', 19: '4/05/2021'}, 'carrier_name': {0: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 1: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 2: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 3: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 4: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 5: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 6: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 7: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 8: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 9: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 10: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 11: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 12: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 13: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 14: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 15: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 16: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 17: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 18: 'CGM', 19: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP'}, 'vessel_name': {0: 'MSC RANIA', 1: 'MSC RANIA', 2: 'CMA CGM IVANHOE', 3: 'SEAMAX BRIDGEPORT', 4: 'SEAMAX BRIDGEPORT', 5: 'NAVARINO', 6: 'EXPRESS ATHENS', 7: 'EXPRESS ATHENS', 8: 'NAVIOS UTMOST', 9: 'NAVIOS UTMOST', 10: 'MAERSK SEBAROK', 11: 'MAERSK COLUMBUS', 12: 'EXPRESS ROME', 13: 'EXPRESS ROME', 14: 'MAERSK ATLANTA', 15: 'MAERSK ATLANTA', 16: 'MSC RANIA', 17: 'OOCL WASHINGTON', 18: 'OOCL EUROPE', 19: 'MSC RANIA'}, 'doc_cut': {0: '3/29/2021', 1: '3/29/2021', 2: '4/9/2021', 3: '4/5/2021', 4: '4/5/2021', 5: '4/19/2021', 6: '3/29/2021', 7: '3/29/2021', 8: '4/12/2021', 9: '4/12/2021', 10: '4/6/2021', 11: '4/13/2021', 12: '4/16/2021', 13: '4/15/2021', 14: '3/26/2021', 15: '3/26/2021', 16: '3/29/2021', 17: '3/23/2021', 18: '4/15/2021', 19: '3/29/2021'}, 'container_type': {0: 'HV', 1: 'HV', 2: 'HV', 3: 'HV', 4: 'HV', 5: 'HV', 6: 'HV', 7: 'HV', 8: 'HV', 9: 'HV', 10: '45', 11: '45', 12: 'HV', 13: 'HV', 14: 'HV', 15: '45', 16: '45', 17: 'HV', 18: '2B', 19: '45'}, 'count': {0: 32, 1: 32, 2: 26, 3: 15, 4: 15, 5: 14, 6: 13, 7: 13, 8: 12, 9: 12, 10: 8, 11: 7, 12: 7, 13: 6, 14: 5, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total_df = pd.merge(table_2_df, table_1_df, how='left', on=['origin', 'destination', 'carrier_name'])
```

EDITS

After reviewing your data, it appears that there are some white-space characters on the destination field in table 2

```
import pandas as pd

table_1_data = {
    'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14,
              15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19},
    'origin': {0: 'NEW YORK', 1: 'NEW YORK', 2: 'NEW YORK', 3: 'NEW YORK', 4: 'NEW YORK', 5: 'NEW YORK', 6: 'NEW YORK',
               7: 'NEW YORK', 8: 'NEW YORK', 9: 'NEW YORK', 10: 'NEW YORK', 11: 'NEW YORK', 12: 'NEW YORK',
               13: 'NEW YORK', 14: 'NEW YORK', 15: 'NEW YORK', 16: 'NEW YORK', 17: 'NEW YORK', 18: 'NEW YORK',
               19: 'NEW YORK'},
    'destination': {0: 'Aqaba', 1: 'Aqaba', 2: 'Batumi', 3: 'Benghazi', 4: 'Benghazi', 5: 'Bremerhaven', 6: 'El Khoms',
                    7: 'El Khoms', 8: 'El Khoms', 9: 'Jebel Ali', 10: 'Jebel Ali', 11: 'Jebel Ali', 12: 'Klaipeda',
                    13: 'Klaipeda', 14: 'MISURATA', 15: 'MISURATA', 16: 'MISURATA', 17: 'Novorossiysk', 18: 'Odessa',
                    19: 'Odessa'},
    'carrier_name': {0: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 1: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 2: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 3: 'CGM',
                     4: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 5: 'CGM', 6: 'CGM', 7: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 8: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.',
                     9: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 10: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 11: 'ONE NETWORK EXPRESS', 12: 'CGM',
                     13: 'EVERGREEN INTERNATIONAL (U S A)', 14: 'CGM', 15: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 16: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.',
                     17: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 18: 'CGM', 19: 'Cosco Container Line'},
    'medium need': {0: 20.0, 1: 19.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 30.0, 4: 26.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 15.0, 7: 11.0, 8: 12.0, 9: 15.0, 10: 18.0,
                    11: 16.0, 12: 16.0, 13: 10.0, 14: 7.0, 15: 6.0, 16: 7.0, 17: 6.0, 18: 42.0, 19: 26.0}}


table_1_df = pd.DataFrame(table_1_data)

table_2_data = {
    'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14,
              15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19},
    'origin': {0: 'NEW YORK', 1: 'NEW YORK', 2: 'NEW YORK', 3: 'NEW YORK', 4: 'NEW YORK', 5: 'NEW YORK', 6: 'NEW YORK',
               7: 'NEW YORK', 8: 'NEW YORK', 9: 'NEW YORK', 10: 'NEW YORK', 11: 'NEW YORK', 12: 'NEW YORK',
               13: 'NEW YORK', 14: 'NEW YORK', 15: 'NEW YORK', 16: 'NEW YORK', 17: 'NEW YORK', 18: 'NEW YORK',
               19: 'NEW YORK'},
    'destination': {0: 'Aqaba ', 1: 'Aqaba ', 2: 'Aqaba ', 3: 'Aqaba ', 4: 'Aqaba ', 5: 'Aqaba ', 6: 'Aqaba ',
                    7: 'Aqaba ', 8: 'Aqaba ', 9: 'Aqaba ', 10: 'Aqaba ', 11: 'Aqaba ', 12: 'Aqaba ', 13: 'Aqaba ',
                    14: 'Aqaba ', 15: 'Aqaba ', 16: 'Aqaba ', 17: 'Aqaba ', 18: 'Aqaba ', 19: 'Aqaba '},
    'from_': {0: '3/22/2021', 1: '3/29/2021', 2: '4/05/2021', 3: '3/29/2021', 4: '4/05/2021', 5: '4/12/2021',
              6: '3/22/2021', 7: '3/29/2021', 8: '4/12/2021', 9: '4/05/2021', 10: '4/05/2021', 11: '4/12/2021',
              12: '4/12/2021', 13: '4/12/2021', 14: '3/22/2021', 15: '3/22/2021', 16: '3/22/2021', 17: '3/22/2021',
              18: '4/12/2021', 19: '3/29/2021'},
    'to_': {0: '3/29/2021', 1: '4/05/2021', 2: '4/12/2021', 3: '4/05/2021', 4: '4/12/2021', 5: '4/19/2021',
            6: '3/29/2021', 7: '4/05/2021', 8: '4/19/2021', 9: '4/12/2021', 10: '4/12/2021', 11: '4/19/2021',
            12: '4/19/2021', 13: '4/19/2021', 14: '3/29/2021', 15: '3/29/2021', 16: '3/29/2021', 17: '3/29/2021',
            18: '4/19/2021', 19: '4/05/2021'},
    'carrier_name': {0: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 1: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 2: 'HAPAG LLOYD',
                     3: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 4: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP',
                     5: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 6: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 7: 'HAPAG LLOYD',
                     8: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 9: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 10: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.',
                     11: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 12: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 13: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 14: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.',
                     15: 'MAERSK LINES, INC.', 16: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP', 17: 'HAPAG LLOYD', 18: 'CGM',
                     19: 'MEDITERRANEAN SHIPPING CORP'},
    'vessel_name': {0: 'MSC RANIA', 1: 'MSC RANIA', 2: 'CMA CGM IVANHOE', 3: 'SEAMAX BRIDGEPORT',
                    4: 'SEAMAX BRIDGEPORT', 5: 'NAVARINO', 6: 'EXPRESS ATHENS', 7: 'EXPRESS ATHENS', 8: 'NAVIOS UTMOST',
                    9: 'NAVIOS UTMOST', 10: 'MAERSK SEBAROK', 11: 'MAERSK COLUMBUS', 12: 'EXPRESS ROME',
                    13: 'EXPRESS ROME', 14: 'MAERSK ATLANTA', 15: 'MAERSK ATLANTA', 16: 'MSC RANIA',
                    17: 'OOCL WASHINGTON', 18: 'OOCL EUROPE', 19: 'MSC RANIA'},
    'doc_cut': {0: '3/29/2021', 1: '3/29/2021', 2: '4/9/2021', 3: '4/5/2021', 4: '4/5/2021', 5: '4/19/2021',
                6: '3/29/2021', 7: '3/29/2021', 8: '4/12/2021', 9: '4/12/2021', 10: '4/6/2021', 11: '4/13/2021',
                12: '4/16/2021', 13: '4/15/2021', 14: '3/26/2021', 15: '3/26/2021', 16: '3/29/2021', 17: '3/23/2021',
                18: '4/15/2021', 19: '3/29/2021'},
    'container_type': {0: 'HV', 1: 'HV', 2: 'HV', 3: 'HV', 4: 'HV', 5: 'HV', 6: 'HV', 7: 'HV', 8: 'HV', 9: 'HV',
                       10: '45', 11: '45', 12: 'HV', 13: 'HV', 14: 'HV', 15: '45', 16: '45', 17: 'HV', 18: '2B',
                       19: '45'},
    'count': {0: 32, 1: 32, 2: 26, 3: 15, 4: 15, 5: 14, 6: 13, 7: 13, 8: 12, 9: 12, 10: 8, 11: 7, 12: 7, 13: 6, 14: 5,
              15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1}}

table_2_df = pd.DataFrame(table_2_data)
table_2_df['destination'] = table_2_df['destination'].str.strip()


total_df = pd.merge(table_2_df, table_1_df, how='left', on=['origin', 'destination', 'carrier_name'])

print(total_df)
    index_x    origin destination  ... count index_y medium need
0         0  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    32     1.0        19.0
1         1  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    32     1.0        19.0
2         2  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    26     0.0        20.0
3         3  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    15     1.0        19.0
4         4  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    15     1.0        19.0
5         5  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    14     1.0        19.0
6         6  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    13     0.0        20.0
7         7  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    13     0.0        20.0
8         8  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    12     1.0        19.0
9         9  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...    12     1.0        19.0
10       10  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     8     NaN         NaN
11       11  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     7     NaN         NaN
12       12  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     7     0.0        20.0
13       13  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     6     0.0        20.0
14       14  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     5     NaN         NaN
15       15  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     2     NaN         NaN
16       16  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     1     1.0        19.0
17       17  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     1     0.0        20.0
18       18  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     1     NaN         NaN
19       19  NEW YORK       Aqaba  ...     1     1.0        19.0
[20 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: its actually gives me column without values

Comment: Are all the key-columns (origin, destination, carrier_name) formatted the same? Are there white-space characters padding some of the entries? Are some uppercase in one table and lower case in the other (or vice versa)?  Does the origin-desitnation-carrier_name actually map to both tables?

Comment: @Vova would you be able to write some of the example data you have into your question so we could build a dataframe exactly as you see it?

Comment: Yes, they formatted the same. I removed white space with ```column.str().strip()```, but for now it doesn't even create the column. And what does mean "map to both tables"?

Comment: Mapping means that there are key's in table 1 that exist in table 2.  It looks like there are matches based on the pictures you posted in your question. But it would be helpful if you wrote some of the data in the tables into some code that we could try solutions together

Comment: @Vova see the setup here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/6770704

Comment: Probably i get it from excel file and it very huge. Or you need just converted it to dictionary ?

Comment: Just load the data-frames from excel, take the first 20 rows from each dataframe into a new df (subset_df = table_1_df.head(20)), convert it into a dict (print(subset_df.to_dict('records') and paste that into your question, appropriately labeled table 1 or table 2

Comment: added into the body. Thank you

Comment: oh my god, thank you, it works. But i tried to remove white space with `df2.columns.strip()` why didn't it remove them from data?

Comment: it's because you applied strip to the df.columns, which is a list of the column names.  You have to apply the function to the data within the columns. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270483/6770704

Comment: Got you, Thanks. Also, how to remove these columns "index_y" and "index_x"?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: omg, foreget to do `total_df = totad_df.drop()` , did just  `totad_df.drop()` instead of

Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a vlookup between the two tables, like this:

```py
try:
    for origin in df2["origin"].values:
        for destination in df2["destination"].values:
            for carrier_name in df2["carrier_name"].values:
                mask1 = (
                    (df1["origin"] == origin)
                    & (df1["destination"] == destination)
                    & (df1["carrier_name"] == carrier_name)
                )
                medium_need = df1.loc[mask1, "medium need"].item()
                mask2 = (
                    (df2["origin"] == origin)
                    & (df2["destination"] == destination)
                    & (df2["carrier_name"] == carrier_name)
                )
                df2.loc[mask2, "medium need"] = medium_need
except ValueError:
    continue
```

Comment: it gives me ```python ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: The second and third loops were missing a ".values", sorry. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry, same result(((

Comment: There was another typo (the name "country" was wrongly used, instead of "origin"). Try again with the code I've just updated.

Comment: actaully, i changed it before. but it is still the same  

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/proje/PycharmProjects/wheellable/123.py", line 26, in <module>
    medium_need = df_report.loc[mask1, "medium need"].item()
  File "C:\Users\proje\PycharmProjects\wheellable\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 420, in item
    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar ```

Comment: OK, I see, the problem comes from the fact that `df1.loc[mask1, "medium need"]` don't probably always return a value, in which cas `.item()`raises a `ValueError`. Try using a try/except statement, like in the updated answer.

Comment: yeah, i added it, but i just received empty column without any values

Comment: I updated the code in order to iterate on df2 keys (instead of df1) as a test: if you run the code and still obtain an empty column, it would mean that values of "origin", "destination" or "carrier_name" are not the same in both df1 and df2.

Comment: for now i have another problem, the infinity run))