# Properly trimming whitespace across an entire pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace, trim

I am trying to accomplish a simple task of trimming all whitespace across every column in my dataframe. I have some values that have trailing spaces after words, before words, and some columns that only contain a `"   "` value. I want all of that stripped.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788913/pythonic-efficient-way-to-strip-whitespace-from-every-pandas-data-frame-cell-tha) which gave a great way to accomplish this:
`data_frame_trimmed = data_frame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)`

However, I frequently get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-31d35db1d48c> in <module>
      1 df = (pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\wundermahn\Desktop\\aggregated_po_data.csv',
----> 2                     encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if (x.dtype == "object") else x))
      3 print(df.shape)
      4 
      5 label = df['class']

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879 
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    294             try:
    295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
--> 296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )
    298             except ValueError as err:

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

<ipython-input-9-31d35db1d48c> in <lambda>(x)
      1 df = (pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\wundermahn\Desktop\\aggregated_data.csv',
----> 2                     encoding = "ISO-8859-1", low_memory=False).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if (x.dtype == "object") else x))
      3 print(df.shape)
      4 
      5 label = df['ON_TIME']

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    185             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    186             return self._accessor
--> 187         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    188         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    189         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in __init__(self, data)
   2039 
   2040     def __init__(self, data):
-> 2041         self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
   2042         self._is_categorical = is_categorical_dtype(data)
   2043         self._is_string = data.dtype.name == "string"

c:\python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py in _validate(data)
   2096 
   2097         if inferred_dtype not in allowed_types:
-> 2098             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
   2099         return inferred_dtype
   2100 

**AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!**
```

So, in trying to find a workaround, I stumbled upon this post, which suggests using:

`data_frame_trimmed = data_frame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "str" else x)`

But, that doesn't strip away empty cells that just contain spaces or tabs.

How can I efficiently strip away all variants of white space? I ultimately am going to drop columns with more than 50% `null` values.

Comment: Do you know in advance what's the type of your columns?

Comment: I do not. That's the issue -- the dataframe is sort of given to me in the form of a `sql` query. I don't know much about the data at all. And the shape is about `(401801, 267)`, so it is quite cumbersome to attempt to go through column by column. I am sorry @RiccardoBucco

Answer (score 1):

You can try `try` instead:

```
def trim(x):
    try:
        return x.str.strip()
    except:
        return x

df = df.apply(trim)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check not column type, but the type of each **individual** value,
so the code can be e.g.:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) == str else x)
```

The reason is that:

- there can be a column of *object* type,
- containing a *string* in almost all cells,
- but some of them can be *NaN* which is a special case of *float*, hence
  you can not call *strip* on it.

But this way you execute unnecessarily the code for columns of types
other than *object*, where nothing will be changed.
If this bothers you, run this code only for columns in which it is likely
to change anything:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) == str else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `select_dtypes` first to select correct columns:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],
                   'col2':list('abc'),
                   'col3':[4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
                   'col4':[' foo', '   bar', 'foobar. ']})

   col1 col2  col3      col4
0     1    a   4.0       foo
1     2    b   5.0       bar
2     3    c   6.0  foobar.
```

```
str_cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[str_cols] = df[str_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

print(df)
   col1 col2  col3     col4
0     1    a   4.0      foo
1     2    b   5.0      bar
2     3    c   6.0  foobar.
```

Comment: Your approach is similar to OP's. It will fail if there is a column with, e.g., list values.

Comment: This is a nice attempt! I didn't approach it this way, but what I found is that `object` columns contain different values. For example, sometimes `A` and sometimes 1 and sometimes `"        "`