# Need To Remove First And Last \n From DataFrame Text

Tags: python, lambda

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
"\n mark has \n no name",
"\n john walks his \n dog",
"mary is fun \n",
"tim is \n old"
```

```py
data = [
    "\n mark has \n no name",
    "\n john walks his \n dog",
    "mary is fun \n",
    "tim is \n old"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Sentences'])
```

How can I write a function, ideally a lambda, as I have not much practice with it, that will replace the first `\n` and last `\n` only in each of the above, so the output is:

```
"mark has \n no name",
"john walks his \n dog",
"mary is fun",
"tim is \n old"
```

Ideally, I would like the output to be a separate column on the data frame, as opposed to replacing what is there.

I have seen formulas that deal with a global replacement, but I need something a bit more specific.

Comment: You can `strip()` the elements in `data` prior to adding them to the data frame. Something like this `df = pd.DataFrame([_.strip() for _ in data], columns=['Sentences'])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic/efficient way to strip whitespace from every Pandas Data frame cell that has a stringlike object in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788913/pythonic-efficient-way-to-strip-whitespace-from-every-pandas-data-frame-cell-tha) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789292/843953)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not a lambda, but the below code *seems* to fit the bill. The basic approach is to iterate through the dataframe, row by row, and test each string for whether it starts or ends with `\n`, then use string indices to return a string that doesn't have that character.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["\n mark has \n no name","\n john walks his \n dog","mary is fun \n","tim is \n old"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Sentences'])


def replace_newline(dataframe_row, col_name, input_string):
    test_string = dataframe_row[col_name]

    if test_string.startswith(input_string):
        return_string = test_string[len(input_string):]
        return return_string

    elif test_string.endswith(input_string):
        return_string = test_string[:-(len(input_string))]
        return return_string

    else:
        return test_string

df['Sentences_edited'] = df.apply(replace_newline, col_name='Sentences', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. `str.strip()` does exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: ^ And much faster than an `apply`

Answer (score -1):

```py
df['fixed'] = df.Sentences.str.strip("\n")
```

or, in case you want more granular control over what to strip on the left / right:

```py
df['fixed'] = df.Sentences.str.lstrip("\n").str.rstrip("\n")
```

pandas has [Vectorized string functions for Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), so you can do `colum.str`, then apply common string methods such as [`lstrip` and `rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip).

Comment: Why `lstrip` and `rstrip` and not just `strip`?

Comment: It gives you the flexibility to strip different charsets on either side

Comment: For the question asked by the OP, they just add unnecessary complexity.