# How to remove whitespace from df column headers (strip isn't working)

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen this question asked a few times, but the suggested answers don't seem to be working for me.  I've brought in a csv with read_csv and am trying to clean up the names, which are initially:

```
In [89]: data.columns
Out[89]: 
Index(['Node Number', 'X [ m ]', 'Y [ m ]', 'Z [ m ]',
       'Turbulence Kinetic Energy [ m^2 s^-2 ]', 'turbulenceIntensity',
       'Velocity u [ m s^-1 ]', 'Velocity v [ m s^-1 ]',
       'Velocity w [ m s^-1 ]', 'windspeedratio'],
      dtype='object')
```

The simplest suggestion I've found should be:

```
data.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)
```

But if I try that, absolutely nothing changes.  Same with

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You want to remove all the whitespace? `strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, of which there is none.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you need `replace` all `' '` to `''`

```
df.columns.str.replace(' ','')
Out[103]: 
Index(['NodeNumber', 'X[m]', 'Y[m]', 'Z[m]',
       'TurbulenceKineticEnergy[m^2s^-2]', 'turbulenceIntensity',
       'Velocityu[ms^-1]', 'Velocityv[ms^-1]', 'Velocityw[ms^-1]',
       'windspeedratio'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: This will work if all he wants to do is print but it won't work if he wants a permanent removal of white spaces from column names. You'll need to assign your line above back to df.columns.

Comment: Ha, thanks that's an easy one then.  I was reading the strip(0 documentation to quickly and missed that it was only leading and trailing whitespace.  I was following this particular question which worked for them, but wasn't clear about only leading and trailing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606987/how-can-i-strip-the-whitespace-from-pandas-dataframe-headers

Comment: @BenjaminBrannon yw~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Strip only removes leading and trailing whitespace. If you want to remove all whitespace (including all kinds of whitesapce like tabs, newlines, spaces, etc), the following will work

```
import string
def remove_whitespace(x):
    table = {ord(char): None for char in string.whitespace}
    return x.translate(table)

data.rename(columns=remove_whitespace, inplace=True)
```

As Brad mentions, the following can be used to the same effect.

```
df.columns.str.replace(r'\s+', '')
```

Comment: Thanks this works too, but the answer from @Wen was more succinct.

Comment: Sure thing. Since Wen covered the simple case, my intention was to demonstrate a solution that works for all whitespace, not just the space character. Cheers.

Comment: That would just be `f.columns.str.replace(r'\s+', '')`

Comment: Nice @BradSolomon - Wasn't aware it would take a regex pattern string.