# Python : Create dictionary keys from renamed pandas columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dictionary

This stripes out the unwanted white space from the column headings when we parse from an excel file with multiple sheets.

`df = {key: sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()) for key, sheet in pd.read_excel(filename).items()}`

But if I want to parse from a csv file instead, and not from an excel with sheets, how do I do this?

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=";", header=0, encoding="iso-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False)

keys_df = df.rename(columns={lambda x: x.strip()})
```

doesn't seem to work.

I want to do it in **dictionary keys**, not a list.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606987/how-can-i-strip-the-whitespace-from-pandas-dataframe-headers)  did not help me, as I want to create dictionary keys from the renamed columns.

Comment: please give us a sample of filename.csv and your expected output.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(...)` returns a `DataFrame`. CSV files don't have sheets so you don't get a `dict` item back from it. So when you apply `.items()` to it it's `DataFrame.items()` you're trying to use and that's not going to work... Are you trying to treat a load of CSV files each as sheets or...?

Comment: What do you want to do with the dictionary? I spy with my little eye, an XY problem

Comment: I want to  stripe out the unwanted white space from the column headings when I parse from a csv file.

Comment: I updated the code with what I'm trying now but I get the error at the  `keys_df` line :  `TypeError: 'set' object is not callable`

Comment: first rename the columns `df.columns = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]` and then assign it to keys_df as `keys_df = {x:[] for x in df.columns}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract a dataframe from a csv file and strip the column names:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=";", header=0, encoding="iso-8859-1",
                 error_bad_lines=False).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```