# Pandas CSV not detecting second column onward

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file generated by some program.
I am trying to read CSV using panda:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

It's reading it successfully and I can display columns using `file.columns`

```
output: `Index(['col1', ' \tcol2', ' \tcol3',
       ' \tcol4', ' \tcol5', ' \tcol6', ' \tcol7',
       ' \tcol8', ' \tcol9', ' \tcol10', ' \tcol11',
       ' \tcol12', ' \tcol13'],
      dtype='object')`
```

I can read the first col using `column_1 = file.col1`
But when I am trying to read any other column, it's giving me an error as :
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col2'`

I figured out that it might be due to tabs and spaces in columns, so I tried removing them using

`file = file.replace(r'\r+|\n+|\t+','', regex=True)`
But it didn't remove anything.

I tried following as well based on many other answers:

```
file = file.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

and

```
file = file.replace('\t','', regex=True)
```

But none of them are removing anything.

Comment: Can you add the output of `file` and the csv file? Just a small sample of a few rows for both

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Yes, it does. Thanks for pointing me towards it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it using:

```
file = file.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```

It removed all white spaces.
I took it from this answer: [How can I strip the whitespace from Pandas DataFrame headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606987/how-can-i-strip-the-whitespace-from-pandas-dataframe-headers)

Answer (score 0):

use `df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())`

Comment: I tried but it didn't do anything.