# How to print single columns with Pandas data Frame in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, columnsorting

I have loaded my csv file with pandas I have displayed the Dataframe, I have also accessed the Dataframe information.I have been able to access the first column by name the rest of the columns are showing an error message.

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('cali_avocados.csv')
df.head()
    Year    Commodity Code  Crop Name   County Code County  Harvested Acres Yield   Production  Price P/U   Unit    Value
0   2020    221999  AVOCADOS ALL    53  Monterey    223 5.56    1240    2379.84 Tons    2951000
1   2020    221999  AVOCADOS ALL    65  Riverside   3020                Tons    88697000
2   2020    221999  AVOCADOS ALL    71  San Bernardino  370 2.16    799 2617.02 Tons    2091000
3   2020    221999  AVOCADOS ALL    73  San Diego   14400   3.51    50500   3028.87 Tons    152958000
4   2020    221999  AVOCADOS ALL    79  San Luis Obispo 4240    5.9 25000   1886.76 Tons    47169000
```

```
df['Year']
0      2020
1      2020
2      2020
3      2020
4      2020
       ... 
415    1980
416    1980
417    1980
418    1980
419    1980
Name: Year, Length: 420, dtype: int64
```

**When I try to access any other column in the data set, I get an error**

```
df['Production']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:


pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()


KeyError: 'Production'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'Production'
```

Comment: What does `df.columns` return?

Comment: I would like to be able to pull columns by name ```df['production']```

Comment: It could be that there are some whitespaces in the columns' names. Please report what `df.columns` returns, as @ozacha suggested.

Comment: ```df.columns     Index(['Year', ' Commodity Code', ' Crop Name', ' County Code', ' County',
       ' Harvested Acres', ' Yield', ' Production', ' Price P/U', ' Unit',
       ' Value'],
      dtype='object')```

Comment: Indeed you have a whitespace before `Production`, `df[' Production']` should work. Or better, you could [remove all the whitespaces in the columns' names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21606987/17203221)

Comment: Thanks it worked it was the spaces. I have used _strip_. ```df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('_')```